# Text Area Restrict Action Script3

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea, flash-builder, restrict

The following code doesnt work:

```
<s:TextArea name = "Desc1" id="Desc1" x="8" y="233" width="162" height="369" restrict="^&"/>
```

im trying to not allow the user to input de "&",in flash it works well but in textarea of flash builder it gets me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing `"^&amp;"`. The `&` character in an mxml tag must be html-escaped. It's the same if you try to write an AND condition in a bound property (`text="{bool1 &amp;&amp; bool2?'ok':'ko'}"`), it's highly unreadable but useful.